# Combining two tables with some matching IDs but not all

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two tables. Both tables have some matching IDs but not all IDs are in each table. I need to be able to combine the two. Example down below:

Table 1

```
Name      Money    ID
Bob       500      1
Nick      600      2
Kim       575      3
```

Table 2

```
Name      Fees    ID
Bob       200      1
Nick      250      2
Ian       100      4
```

OUTPUT

```
Name    Money   Fees  ID
Bob     500     200   1
Nick    600     250   2
Kim     575           3
Ian             100   4
```

Comment: I'd guess your question might be seen as too broad for the SO Q&A format, possible answers would need to be tutorials all-about basic concepts, normalization, primary keys as unique row identifiers in each table, foreign keys. Your tables would perhaps need be three or one instead of two, one storing your four Persons, one storing their FK-related Money rows if there can be more than one per person, one would store the FK-related Fee rows if there can be more than one per person, and then you'd Join them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple `full outer join` with some `coalesce` to keep the values in a single column:

```
select coalesce(tbl1.[Name], tbl2.[Name]) [Name]
    , tbl1.[Money]
    , tbl2.Fees
    , coalesce(tbl1.ID, tbl2.ID) ID
from tbl1
full outer join tbl2
    on tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID
order by ID
```

Comment: Would this logic work if there's 3 tables also? Just full outer join all 3 tables?

Comment: @brockey2sockey `FULL JOIN` on three or more tables is a little more complicated, you need conditions such as `ON ISNULL(tbl2.ID, tbl1.ID) = tbl3.ID`